# Mi aplicación se ejecuta en mi PC, pero no en otros (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, visual, studio

he creado una aplicación para windows en C#, cree el instalador y la he probado en mi PC y funciona correctamente, se instala y se ejecuta normalmente, pero al probarla en otro PC, la aplicacion se instala correctamente, pero al momento de ejecutarla no pasa nada, aparece el símbolo de cargando un rato pero luego no pasa nada

En las opciones de publicación tengo las siguientes opciones:
[image: Ventana de requisitos previos]

[image: ventana de archivos de aplicación]

he leído por internet que el problema puede ser en el empaquetador de datos (o algo así), no sé si es eso, y si es, no sé como arreglarlo, agradeceria mucho la ayuda, he buscado en todos lados pero no encuentro nada

Comment: Y termino de instalar los prerequisitos??? tu pc no es parametro para saber si el instalador funciona... alguna informacion mas de que hace tu programa?

Comment: Es un programa relativamente sencillo, lo unico "fuera de lo comun" es el uso de la libreria spreadsheetlight, para crear y editar archivos excel sin necesidad de tener microsoft Office instalado.

Comment: y esa libreria va? esta instalada?

Comment: Si, si va en el instalador

Comment: Has comprobado que al instalarla se instala bien el .NET 4.7.2? El modo de compilacion está en x32 o x64? Si solamente ejecutas el .exe de la carpeta bin/debug o bin/release funciona?